# On refreshing page, react router state shows old state

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

I'm using react-router-dom of version 4.2.2.

In my application, I have two pages.

I'm using Link to redirect and I'm passing state while coming from 2nd page to 1st page to show notification.

```
<Link
    to={{
      pathname: '/page1',
      state: { success: true }
}}>
```

Based on success state, I decide to show notification.

After coming back to page1, if I refresh that page, I keep seeing notification because react-router state is not cleared. I just want to show notification when I come back to page1 from page2. So how do I clear react-router state without redirecting to the same path?

How do i solve this problem?